# AOT with JHipster: module.ngfactory files not being generated for lazy loaded modules

Tags: angular, webpack, jhipster

[My app](https://github.com/dancancro/great-big-example-application/blob/meals/webpack/webpack.prod.js#L38) runs fine with a dev build, but I'm not getting the AOT production build to work. For each lazy loaded module, I get an error like this:

```
ERROR in ./target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './features/about/about.module.ngfactory' in '/Users/Dan/work/a/gba/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app'
 @ ./target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts 535:190-240
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main-aot.ts
```

and one like this:

```
ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/app.routing.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../../target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/features/about/about.module.ngfactory' in '/Users/Dan/work/a/gba/src/main/webapp/app'
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.routing.ts 15:137-228
 @ ./target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main-aot.ts
```

The paths seems correct but the files for these modules are not there. If I make a lazy loaded module load eagerly, then the error for that one goes away.

I followed the directions from [angular-router-loader](https://github.com/brandonroberts/angular-router-loader/blob/master/docs/options.md#aot-example). I think I did it right but no luck

```
// webpack.prod.js
     { loader: 'angular-router-loader?aot=true&genDir=target/aot' }


// tsconfig-aot.json
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "target/aot",
    "skipMetadataEmit": true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your issue is related with your `tsconfig-aot.json` since angular's compiler looks the files you've handed to tsconfig.

So here is my assumption:

**tsconfig-aot.json**

```
"files": [
    "src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts",
    "src/main/webapp/app/app.main-aot.ts",
    "src/main/webpapp/app/features/about/about.module.ts" <= try to add this
],
```

Comment: Thanks. I believe that the compiler gets to the about module by starting with the app module and traversing: app.module -> app.routing -> about.module. Unfortunately adding about.module to tsconfig didn't help.

Comment: How can i reproduce it? I don't see about module in your repo

Comment: This solution works for me. I also use `files` option

Comment: The about module is located here. It's in the 'meals' branch https://github.com/dancancro/great-big-example-application/blob/meals/src/main/webapp/app/features/about/about.module.ts

Comment: Apparently, according to this, the angular-router-loader doesn't handle AOT. So I'm now looking at using @ngtools/webpack instead https://github.com/brandonroberts/angular-router-loader/issues/72#issuecomment-292568301

Comment: Yes, i use `@ngtools/webpack` in my application. There is an alternative loader for router that supports aot https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/blob/master/config/webpack.common.js#L128 https://github.com/shlomiassaf/ng-router-loader

Comment: Thanks. I think your original solution might work after all. I was in the middle of switching to @ngtools when testing it and I had a typo. Correcting those and adding the lazy loaded files to tsconfig eliminated the errors. I'm now fixing some new ones. Mine is a Jhipster app and they chose to use ngc over ngtools/webpack for some reason. So if possible I'll stick with that.

Comment: I switched my project to use the AngularClass base with ng-router-loader and I think I'm stuck on the same kind of thing. I added all the files to tsconfig.json but this time I get only one error about a single module, I think singled out only because it's the first encountered. The error is here https://gist.github.com/dancancro/2417394ff9afa8661417f189e21ea092 The new code is here on the 'angularclass' branch https://github.com/dancancro/great-big-example-application/tree/angularclass